# AngularJS link not working, but manual page refresh works fine

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm working on this site in AngularJS. I'm having an issue that when I click on the nav links ( tag with a href), the url is changing, but the page content is not getting updated. So if I click on the 'About' link, the url gets modified to #/about, but not the content. However, if I manually refresh the page now, the content loads.

See the site at: www.arunmahendrakar.com/nsm/

The links are 'outside' Angular and I'm not sure where I need to add the $apply function, if at all.

The nsm.controller.js has the routing and the controller details, nsm.services.js has a service that gets the data from the server and the nsm.directives.js is used to highlight the current link.

The index.html page uses bootstrap 3.0.

Please let me know how I can fix this issue.

Comment: I don't know if it's pretty normal for you but you got a message error in the console : OPTIONS http://arunmahendrakar.com/nsm/data/about.txt Origin http://www.arunmahendrakar.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Now that's strange Thomas, cos hadn't seen that before.

Comment: It s your matter you re not on the same origin.  So the network abort for security reason. Look at cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a flicker on the page when you navigate, so angular is noticing the change and trying to update the page.

The problem looks like your directives.js which adds a listener on the $location.path()

```
scope.$watch('location.path()', function (newPath) {...});
```

According to the discussion [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location#comment-587323848), you want to use

```
$scope.$watch(function() {return location.path()}, function(path) {...});
```

Probably the call to $location.path() is interfering with the routing.

**EDIT**

The following might explain it:

```
services.factory('pageData', ['$resource', '$route',
   function ($resource, $route) {
       // this is done so I can run the e2e tests from the :8000 port
       //debugger;
       var slug = ($route.current.params.slug || 'home') + '.txt';
       return $resource('http://arunmahendrakar.com/nsm/data/:slug', { slug: slug });
   }]);

services.factory('pageDataLoader', ['pageData', '$q',
  function (pageData, $q) {
      return function () {
          var delay = $q.defer();
          pageData.query(function (pData) {
              delay.resolve(pData);
          }, function () {
              delay.reject('Unable to fetch data');
          });
          return delay.promise;
      };
  }]);
```

The pageData factory returns a $resource object. This is only called once, when the page loads. The pageDataLoader factory returns a function. This function is invoked each time a pageDataLoader is instantiated.

Comment: It's not that Sam. I did not enable those images on purpose. The image stuff is working just fine locally.

Comment: Nope. So to rule out that possibility, I've completely removed all references of the directives code from the app. I'm still facing the same issue. However, I see that when I click on another link, it still loads the home.txt from cache (see the Network trace in dev tools) although the text file should be different. The app in the above link has been updated. I can upload the code if that'll help.

Comment: I used your comments from previous edits as a change for the directives. Although that was not the causing the issue, it was better code. I agree with your last comment on $resource. I changed my code to do a .get and that fixed all the issues. Thanks a bunch Sam.